# Validar una fecha y darle formato personalizado

Tags: java, date

El método `parse()` no me esta devolviendo el formato correcto. Estoy tratando de pasar del formato mes/día/año a día/mes/año.

Primero, la fecha la obtengo desde un archivo excel utilizando java POI con el método `formatCellValue()` de la clase `DataFormatter` Esto me devuelve un String con el formato mes/dia/año algo así: `3/1/19`. Luego de parsear el formato me devuelve algo así

> Thu Jan 03 00:01:00 BOT 2019

Por aquí dejo mi código:

```
String fecha_string = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(fila_hoja.getCell(4));
System.out.println("Formato de fecha original " + fecha_string);

Date convertido = null;

//convertir la fecha en Date
DateFormat fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
//System.out.println(fecha);

try {
    convertido = fecha.parse(fecha_string);

} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Secuencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

System.out.println(convertido);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas tener dos formatos, uno que determine el formato inicial y otro para el formato final de la fecha.

```
//String fecha_string = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(fila_hoja.getCell(4));
String fecha_string = "3/1/19"; //Tome la fecha que colocaste como referencia para probar
try {
    SimpleDateFormat formato_inicial = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    SimpleDateFormat formato_final = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date fecha = formato_inicial.parse(fecha_string); //Obtienes un Date del formato inicial con la fecha string

    System.out.println(formato_final.format(fecha));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Secuencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Salida:

> 01/03/2019

Corriendo: https://rextester.com/CKF17120
Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169655/8451749

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de César es correcta y más que suficiente, pero por comodidad, te recomiendo que uses LocalDate en lugar de Date. A mi juicio tiene unos métodos más fáciles de usar y el parseo de fechas suele ser sencillo.

Esta clase tiene los siguientes métodos principales (hay más):

```
//Tomaremos "ld" como un objeto de la clase LocalDate

LocalDate.parse(String p) //Pasa de String a fecha
LocalDate.now() //Devuelve la fecha actual
ld.getMonth()//Obtener mes actual (getMonthValue() devuelve el numero de mes)
ld.getYear() //Devuelve el año
ld.getDay() //devuelve día del año (también puedes devolver día del mes y día de la semana

//Distintas operaciones de suma de fechas 
ld.plusDays(int days) //Suma días
ld.minusDays(int days) //Resta días
```

Puedes consultar la documentación de la clase en Internet por si tienes alguna duda, o quieres seguir explorando los métodos (algunos muy interesantes para la manipulación de fechas)

También tienes LocalTime (funciona parecido) para manipular horas si lo consideras preciso

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/147775)

Comment: Tienes razón! Edito el post y lo anoto para la próxima vez!