# ¿Cómo invalidar fechas con expresiones regulares?

Tags: java, regex, date

Tengo que hacer un programa para aceptar usuarios y el día en el que se dan de alta; el problema es con la fecha y el formato que me pide para almacenarlo en la base de datos el cual es "AAAA-MM-DD".

Como pueden ver mi código en la expresión regular es ineficiente, tengo una linea de código comentada que se supone que es igual a la que estoy usando sin embargo no se puede utilizar ya que no me acepta fechas del intervalo de los días 10 a 20 ejemplo "2020-02-15" lo arregle haciendo que me aceptara los datos como lo muestro, lo que hace que mi código sea muy largo y por ende ineficiente.

Como segundo problema, es que el usuario puede poner una fecha invalida, la cual es "2020-00-15" ósea el mes 00 el cual no existe, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de invalidar esto ultimo y cual es problema de la linea de código comentada.

Codigo:

```
public static boolean validarFecha(String fecha){
    fecha=fecha.trim();
    //return fecha.matches("[2]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[-]{1}[0-12]{2}[-]{1}[1-31]{2}");
        return fecha.matches("[2]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[-]{1}[0-12]{2}[-]{1}[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]{2}");
}

System.out.println("Teclee la fecha de ingreso(aaaa-mm-dd): ");
datosEmpleado.setDFECING(teclado.nextLine());

while(validarFecha(datosEmpleado.getDFECING())==false)
{
    if (validarFecha(datosEmpleado.getDFECING())==true){
        System.out.println("Fecha valida");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Fecha no valida");
        System.out.println("Teclee la Fecha: ");
        datosEmpleado.setDFECING(teclado.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Y por qué intentas validar la fecha con un regex y no directamente crear un objeto de tipo fecha con el patrón que necesitas? `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(fecha.trim());`, si luego `date` es null es que no era una fecha correcta

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Formato erróneo de fecha devuelto incorrecto Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249897/formato-err%c3%b3neo-de-fecha-devuelto-incorrecto-java)